# Grouping dates across fields in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

Let's say that I have a table that looks like this:

```
STUD_ID    TEST_REG_DATE    TEST_CONF_DATE    TEST_TAKEN_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------
1          02/01/2014       03/01/2015        05/01/2015
1          01/01/2015       03/01/2015        05/01/2015
2          05/01/2014       07/01/2014        10/01/2015
2          05/01/2014       08/01/2015        10/01/2015
2          04/01/2015       07/01/2014        10/01/2015
2          04/01/2015       08/01/2015        10/01/2015
```

STUD_ID = Student ID
TEST_REG_DATE = Test registration date
TEST_CONF_DATE = Test confirmation date
TEST_TAKEN_DATE = Test taken date

So basically, this table is supposed to show the student, the date the student registered for the test, the date the student confirmed their registration, and the date the student actually took the test. As shown in the table, each student has two test registration dates. I want to be able to see whether or not the student completed the entire registration process for each test registration date. So basically, did they complete the process before having another test registration date attached to their record? The resulting table would ideally look like this:

```
STUD_ID    TEST_REG_DATE    TEST_CONF_DATE    TEST_TAKEN_DATE   COMPLETE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          02/01/2014       NULL              NULL              0
1          01/01/2015       03/01/2015        05/01/2015        1
2          05/01/2014       07/01/2014        NULL              0
2          04/01/2015       08/01/2015        10/01/2015        1
```

I don't know how to group dates across fields in this manner, or if it's even possible. I am using Netezza.

Comment: Your sample data generate that result? I dont see why `stud=1 date 02/01/2014`  is null. Also why `stud =1` have two nulls and `stud =2` only 1Can you explain the rules a litle more, what are you checking?

Comment: The "result" table is what I want to generate, not what was actually generated. I don't even know if it's possible to generate it.

Basically, I want each test registration date to only be associated with the confirmation and test taken dates in the future that are not after a future registration date. So for student 1, they had registration dates on 02/01/2014 and 01/01/2015. Since both the confirmation date and the test taken dates for that student are after 01/01/2015, I don't want those dates associated with the 02/01/2014 record.

Comment: For student 2, the first confirmation date is after the first registration date but BEFORE the second registration date, so TEST_CONF_DATE is not null for the 05/01/2014 record. Sorry I know this is confusing but I hope this explanation helped.

Comment: Your desire result shouldnt have 4 rows for stud = 2?

Comment: I wouldn't want it to, no, because ideally I'd only like one row per registration date. Though honestly, the most important thing here is being marked as "Complete" or not. If that field is reflective of what is shown in my "ideal" result table, then the structure of the other fields don't matter as much.

But like I said, I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: Sorry I still dont see the rules. You should edit your question instead of posting comment... First try to include a row_id in you source data even if you dont have it in your table (and btw you should have a primary key) then say something. In `row.1 reg_date < row2.reg_date` then should be null but in `row.4 reg_date < row6.reg_date but not rew7.reg` so should be null ... Is hard to follow when you say `1` but not sure what `1` you are talking

Comment: [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow seems to imply that when test_taken_date is set, then the process was successfully completed. In this case the answer is pretty easy (I think you are missing a test_id or course_id):

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   CASE WHEN t.test_taken_date IS NULL THEN 0
   ELSE 1
   END complete
FROM
   table t
;
```

Or in the form of a where clause, to only return student ids with no uncompleted tests:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE stud_id = t.stud_id AND test_taken_date IS NULL)
```